# Запрет на использование купона после 15.00

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины, wp-plugin

Стоит такая задача, что нужно включать использование купона с 10.00 по 15.00. Только в это время пользователь может применить купон, в остальное время он неактивен.
Может кто-то знает плагин с подобными функциями или как можно реализовать свою функцию для такого ограничения? Была бы очень признательна за любую помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно фильтрами проверять и удалять из корзины

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'remove_coupon_by_date');

function remove_coupon_by_date() {

        global $woocommerce;
        
        $coupon_code = 'COUPON_CODE';
        
        $coupon_start_date = date('Y-m-d').' 10:00:00';
        
        $coupon_end_date = date('Y-m-d').' 15:00:00';

        if ((time() < strtotime($coupon_start_date)) || (time() > strtotime($coupon_end_date))) {
            
            if ($woocommerce->cart->has_discount(sanitize_text_field($coupon_code))) {

                if ($woocommerce->cart->remove_coupons(sanitize_text_field($coupon_code))) {

                    $woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();

                }
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: С вашим кодом теперь купон не применяется совсем. При попытке применить купон, пишет "Время действия этого купона истекло"